# Let $A \subseteq S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $A$ is connected in $S$ if and only if $A$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We say $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is disconnected when there exists open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$U \cap A \neq \emptyset,V \cap A \neq \emptyset, U \cap V=\emptyset, \text{and} A \subseteq U \cup V$$. We say $A$ is connected if it is not disconnected.

Let $A\subseteq S  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that if $A$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $A$ is connected in $S$.

The forward direction is simple, but I don't know how to prove the other direction.

Here's my proof:
If $A$ is disconnected in $S$,I want to show that $A$ is disconnected in $\mathbb{R}^n$. then there exist sets $U,V \subseteq S$ which are open in $S$ such that 
$$U \cap A \neq \emptyset, V\cap A \neq \emptyset, U \cap V=\emptyset,A \subseteq U \cup V$$

Since $U,V$ are open in $S$, there exist open sets $U_0,V_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U=U_{0}\cap S$ and $V=V_{0} \cap S$. We can show that 
$$U_0 \cap A \neq \emptyset, V_0 \cap A \neq \emptyset, U_0 \cap V_0 = \emptyset$$ But how can i show that $A \subseteq U_0 \cup V_0$ I can only show $A \subseteq S \cap (U_0 \cup V_0)$.

Comment: How did you get $U_0 \cap V_0 =\emptyset$?

Comment: @copper.hat  $\emptyset=U \cap V=U_0 \cap V_0 \cap S \Rightarrow U_0 \cap V_0 =\emptyset$

Comment: That does not follow. How do you know that $(U_0 \cap V_0) \setminus S$ is empty?

Comment: @copper.hat i think you are right. What should I do then?

Comment: This is the central issue, I believe.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to talk about the "forward direction" when you've written the statement in two different directions in the title and the text.

Comment: $S\cap(U_0\cup V_0)\subseteq U_0\cup V_0$ is not the hard part

Comment: The result is not true in general topological spaces, one can construct a topology on a space $X$ and a subset $A$ where $A$ is disconnected in the subspace topology but there is no separation in $X$. However, I do not have an example using the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.